# Django's CachedStaticFilesStorage not hashing file urls

Tags: python, css, django, versioning

I wanted to enabling versioning to some of my javascript and css files as I was getting caching problems when working on the site. I read about CachedStaticFilesStorage in Django 1.6 and it seemed perfect. I modified my settings.py to the following settings:

```
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'

STATIC_URL = ''

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.CachedStaticFilesStorage'
```

As a test I then rewrote the most problematic of the css tags to see if it would start hashing the file path. I instead got a 500 error whenever I try and load the page.

Any ideas where I went wrong? Is there an additional step I missed?

The entry in the template:

```
{% block cssfiles %}
{% load static%}
<link href="{% static "/static/css/mapmaker.css" %}" media="screen">
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I'm also not sure how to inject the hash into the filename... {% static %} tag doesn't seem to be doing that... also using Django 1.6

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Very tricky... If you read the docs carefully, you will learn:

> ... use the **`staticfiles`** `static` template tag to refer to your static files in your templates ...

So instead of:

```
{% load static %}
```

Use

```
{% load staticfiles %}
```

Comment: Perfect, annoying that this is a silent fail

Answer (score 2):

This is fixed in Django 1.10, as explained in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage):

> In older versions, you also had to use `{% load static from staticfiles %}` in your template. The static template tag (`{% load static %}`) now uses django.contrib.staticfiles if it’s installed.